# Modify a line below a specific line

Tags: shell

I have a big file like this small example:

```
>ENSG00000002587|ENST00000002596
ATGGCCGCGCTGCTCCTGGGCGCGGTGCTGCTGGTGGCCCAGCCCCAGCTAGTGCCTTCC
>ENSG00000004059|ENST00000000233
ATGGGCCTCACCGTGTCCGCGCTCTTTTCGCGGATCTTCGGGAAGAAGCAGATGCGGATT
>ENSG00000003249|ENST00000002501
ATGGAGCCCCCGGAGGGCGCCGGCACCGGAGAGATCGTTAAGGAGGCTGAGGTGCCGCAG
GCTGCGCTGGGCGTCCCAGCCCAGGGGACAGGGGACAATGGCCACACGCCTGTGGAGGAG
>ENSG00000048028|ENST00000003302
ATGACTGCGGAGCTGCAGCAGGACGACGCGGCCGGCGCGGCAGACGGCCACGGCTCGAGC
TGCCAAATGCTGTTAAATCAACTGAGAGAAATCACAGGCATTCAGGACCCTTCCTTTCTC
CATGAAGCTCTGAAGGCCAGTAATGGTGACATTACTCAGGCAGTCAGCCTTCTCACTGAT
```

I want to remove the first 5 character of every line which is below the line that starts with `>`.
I do not know how to do that in command line. Do you know?

Here is the expected output:

```
>ENSG00000002587|ENST00000002596
CGCGCTGCTCCTGGGCGCGGTGCTGCTGGTGGCCCAGCCCCAGCTAGTGCCTTCC
>ENSG00000004059|ENST00000000233
CCTCACCGTGTCCGCGCTCTTTTCGCGGATCTTCGGGAAGAAGCAGATGCGGATT
>ENSG00000003249|ENST00000002501
GCCCCCGGAGGGCGCCGGCACCGGAGAGATCGTTAAGGAGGCTGAGGTGCCGCAG
GCTGCGCTGGGCGTCCCAGCCCAGGGGACAGGGGACAATGGCCACACGCCTGTGGAGGAG
>ENSG00000048028|ENST00000003302
TGCGGAGCTGCAGCAGGACGACGCGGCCGGCGCGGCAGACGGCCACGGCTCGAGC
TGCCAAATGCTGTTAAATCAACTGAGAGAAATCACAGGCATTCAGGACCCTTCCTTTCTC
CATGAAGCTCTGAAGGCCAGTAATGGTGACATTACTCAGGCAGTCAGCCTTCTCACTGAT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E '/^>/{N;s/\n.{5}/\n/}' file
```

- find line starting with *>*
- join that line with next
- replace newline and five chars with just newline